# How can I intentionally make my toilet make this noise?

Tags: plumbing, toilet

For Halloween I want to haunt my toilets and have them make the noise heard here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6S0zewtkqso

How can I do that?

I think I would just need to cut a slit in a rubber part of the fill valve.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a pissed-off fill valve, acting like a reed. You'd have to get your hands on a crappy toilet, swap out the fill valve, and hope it has a similar failure; not recommended. (all puns intended)

Comment: I happen to have a spare toilet and fill valve. The one pictured in the video is a bog standard replacement valve around here (southern USA). What part am I looking for? A rubber seal that stops or starts the water flow at the top of the valve assembly?

Comment: My job would be to make it *not* do that. I don't know how to *make* it do that. You could hook the extra valve to a temporary supply and fiddle with it to your hearts content; without going and messing with your installed toilet. I'd begin like you say and play with the seating of the stopper seal. -Advertise online for the free replacement of a screaming toilet valve. @Freiheit