# Stool sounds like foghorn!

Tags: plumbing

Our toilet suddenly started sounding like a foghorn, periodically.  Does this mean air in the waterline?  If not, what is going on?  What can we do about it (it is really loud!)?

Comment: What kind of stool has a waterline?

Comment: Where are you located?

Comment: It seems like resonance buildup in the lines

Comment: http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/52760/why-does-my-toilet-make-a-low-pitched-moaning-noise-when-it-refills and http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/52039/how-can-i-intentionally-make-my-toilet-make-this-noise

Comment: Thank you so much Ecnerwal, i have not heard the foghorn in several days!!  It really worked! ( : )

Answer (score 1):

Rebuilding the fill valve internals will likely fix your problem.